# Error : Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Reflection\Project::where()

Tags: laravel, undefined, where-clause, call, laravel-5.8

Doing the Larcast tutorial for "Build a laravel App with TDD" and when i added the `$response->assertRedirect(Project::where($attributes)->first()->path());`

i started getting the following:

> Error : Call to undefined method phpDocumentor\Reflection\Project::where()

How do i resolve this, struggling to find the resolution anywhere else, i have added it to the laracast tutorial itself but no answer.

Tried chasing the answer on the laracasts site.

My tests should pass. (the functionality actually works but i want the test in place to prove it does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong import for the `Project` so on top of the test class put this:

```
use App\Project;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. i had imported use phpDocumentor\Reflection\Project; for some reason and just underneath i also had App\Project; but it was gray... ALL test are passing now. thx.